# Variable 'PlayerInfo::HistoryGuess' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6) error keeps showing up

Tags: c++

```
struct PlayerInfo {
   string Name;
   int InfoNumber;
   string CurrentGuess;
   int HistoryGuess;
   double Time;


};


int main()
{
   struct PlayerInfo player1;
   struct PlayerInfo player2;
   struct PlayerInfo player3;
   struct PlayerInfo player4;
   struct PlayerInfo player5;
```

It keeps warning me that InfoNumber, HistoryGuess and Time are uninitialized, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you writing ```struct PlayerInfo player1``` on instantiation?

Comment: *"what am I doing wrong?"* - Not initializing them ? Ex: what value do you expect `player1.InfoNumber` to have after those decls? *Why* ? Provide a proper default-ctor and/or use value-initialization. (some google-fu terms there).

Comment: And is it an error or a warning? Your title says about error, but in question it is a warnibg

Comment: Yes its a warning, i mistyped

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes thank you I know they are not initialized, I'm new to programming, it would be helpful if told how.

Answer (score 1):

Your warning(s) stem from exactly what they claim. Your trivial members are not specifically initialized.

Your declarations the `player` variables are using *default-construction* of instances of the `PlayerInfo` class. As you have provided no default-ctor for that class type, the compiler generated default version is used instead, which will default-construct any member variables in the order they're declared within the class.

`std::string` provides a proper default-ctor, so your standard string members are handled. But the trivial members (the two `int` and one `double`) members do not. The compiler generated default constructor for those does... *nothing*. It leaves them uninitialized.

Several ways to combat this:

**Provide a proper default-ctor**

The following is a simple default-ctor for that class.  It specifies members initialized with values we want. Note I left out the string members, as they will already be handled for us with compiler-generated default-ctor invocation.

```
struct PlayerInfo {
    std::string Name;
    int InfoNumber;
    std::string CurrentGuess;
    int HistoryGuess;
    double Time;

    PlayerInfo()
        : InfoNumber(0)
        , HistoryGuess(0)
        , Time(0.0)
    {
    }
};
```

**Use value-initialization**

You can use brace syntax value initialization:

```
int main()
{
    PlayerInfo player1{};
    PlayerInfo player2{};
    PlayerInfo player3{};
    PlayerInfo player4{};
    PlayerInfo player5{};
}
```

These are just two of the options. There are others, but these are probably the easiest to understand, especially the first.